# How to drag and drop multiple sprites in inspector in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script which handles many sprite arrays. I didn't want to drag them one by one so I wrote a `CustomEditor` for it that can allow me to assign multiple sprites at once using drag and drop operation:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyMonoBehaviour))]
public class MyMonoBehaviourEditor : Editor
{
    Sprite[] sprites;//actually Sprite[,][] but simplified here

    Object[] DropAreaGUI()
    {
        Event evt = Event.current;
        Rect drop_area = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(0.0f, 20.0f, GUILayout.ExpandWidth(true));
        GUI.Box(drop_area, "Drop here!");

        switch (evt.type)
        {
            case EventType.DragUpdated:
            case EventType.DragPerform:
                if (!drop_area.Contains(evt.mousePosition))
                    return null;

                DragAndDrop.visualMode = DragAndDropVisualMode.Copy;

                if (evt.type == EventType.DragPerform)
                {
                    DragAndDrop.AcceptDrag();
                    return DragAndDrop.objectReferences;
                }
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
    void OnInspectorGUI(){
        var drops = DropAreaGUI();
        if (drops != null)
        {
            //the following line gives me error
            sprites = drops.Select(x => (x as Sprite)).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

I lock the inspector, select 12 sprites from Project, drag them onto the box and when I drop them it gives me this error: `ArgumentException: GUILayout: Mismatched LayoutGroup.DragPerform`

I noticed that `DragAndDrop.objectReferences` returns an `Object[]` which is in my case a `Texture2D[]` and I can't cast it to `Sprite[]`. I tried `Sprite.Create` but it asks for rect and pivot which I don't have.

How can I make DragAndDrop recognize that I am dropping Sprites and not Texture2Ds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to assign multiple sprites to an array in the inspector, you can actually just drag and drop them onto the array itself.

What you'd typically do is select the asset you want to drag them into, then click the padlock in the upper-right of the inspector to lock it. Then you can select multiple objects and drag them onto the array itself (the name of the array with the drop-down menu) rather than into any particular slot of the array. Unity will then automatically populate the array with what you dropped there.

This works with arrays and lists (and possibly other container types, if unity displays them in the inspector).

Comment: That's great :) I was using custom inspector so I guess I just missed this option

Answer (score 2):

I found the workaround.

instead of `return DragAndDrop.objectReferences;` I wrote `return DragAndDrop.paths;`

and then loading is possible:

```
sprites = drops.Select(x => AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<Sprite>(x)).ToArray();
```